# Calling functions and namespacing - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain how the function below works and how I am able to create a new button object? Do I need to call the MYAPP.dom.Button function? I assume 'return b' returns a button object?

```
var MYAPP = {};
MYAPP.dom = {};
MYAPP.dom.Button = function(text, conf) {
    var styles = {
        font: 'Verdana',
        border: '1px solid black',
        color: 'black',
        background: 'grey'        
    };
    function setStyles() {
        for (var i in styles) {
            b.style[i] = conf[i] || styles[i];                            
        }
    }
    conf = conf || {};
    var b = document.createElement('input');
    b.type = conf['type'] || 'submit';
    b.value = text;
    setStyles();
    return b;  
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, `b` refers to a `button` element. You need to call the method of the `MYAPP` object as follows:

```
MYAPP.dom.Button(x, y);
```

For `x` you will need to pass in some text as the `value` of the button and for `y` the need to define the `type` of the button. The `type` of the button defaults to `submit`.

The following `MYAPP.dom.Button('hey');` will return

```
<input type="submit" value="hey" style="border: 1px solid black; color: black; background: grey;">
```

Also as @dreamweiver has said below

> the `y` parameter is also eligible to hold the style of the button, if
>   not passed it would take the default style properties mentioned inside
>   Button function

Comment: @stckpete : just to add up one more thing, `y` parameter is also eligible to hold the style of the button, if not passed it would take the default style properties mentioned inside `Button` function

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new button as:

```
var btnText = 'Go';
var conf['type'] = 'button';
var goBtn = MYAPP.dom.Button(btnText, conf);
```

It will create a button with value Go and type button;

Second parameter is optional, So can also call it as:

```
var goBtn = MYAPP.dom.Button('Submit');
```

It will create a button with text Submit and type submit.

Comment: the second parameter for  `Button` function need to a array & not a string literal

Comment: @KrishanKumarMourya : you need to update your answer bro,not all will read the comments